# Returning HTTP response back to the flow

Tags: visual-workflow, callout

I call an invokable apex class method, that in turn calls an external REST service.
How do I send the http response back to the flow?
Am I missing the invokable return variable?

```
    public class obuTopUpTrailhead {
// Call this method from flow
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void invokeapexcallout(list<String> obuDetails){
    for (string s : obuDetails){
    PutCallout(s);
    }
}   

// http callout method
public static HttpResponse PutCallout(String pName) {
    System.debug('Incoming String is :' + pname);
    String FullString   = pname;
    String[] OBUdetails = fullstring.split(',');
    String recordid     = OBUdetails [0]; 
    String obusn        = OBUdetails [1];
    String topup        = OBUdetails [2];
    String cardnumber   = OBUdetails [3];
    // Make JSON conversion
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);    
    gen.writeStartObject();      
    gen.writeStringField('OBU Record ID ', recordid);
    gen.writeStringField('OBU S/N', obusn);
    gen.writeStringField('Top up Amount', topup);
    gen.writeStringField('Card Number', cardnumber);
    gen.writeEndObject();    
    String jsonS = gen.getAsString();
    System.debug('jsonMaterials'+jsonS);
   
    // Sending the http body with JSON
    String endpoint = 'http://www.example.com/service';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setbody(jsonS);
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
    
    // Parse the JSON response
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
            response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm?search_text=invocable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Funny... I just got done figuring this out myself:

You have to first create a class for all the values in your json response body. Then, deserialize the response.getbody() referencing the newly created class.

Does that make sense?